# How do you use the IS operator with a Type on the left side?

Tags: c#, reflection, static, properties, types

I have a method I'm writing that uses reflection to list a class's static properties, but I'm only interested in those that are of a particular type (in my case, the property must be of a type derived from DataTable). What I would like is something like the if() statement in the following (which presently always returns true):

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = ( typeof(MyType) ).GetProperties( BindingFlags.Public
    | BindingFlags.Static );

foreach( PropertyInfo propertyInfo in properties ) {
    if( !( propertyInfo.PropertyType is DataTable ) )
        continue;

    //business code here
}
```

Thanks, I'm stumped.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use [Type.IsAssignableFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx) instead of the "is" operator.

This would be:

```
if( !( DataTable.IsAssignableFrom(propertyInfo.PropertyType) )
```

`DataTable.IsAssignableFrom(propertyInfo.PropertyType)` will be true if PropertyType is a DataTable or a subclass of DataTable.

Answer (score 1):

```
if( !( propertyInfo.PropertyType.isSubClassOf( typeof(DataTable) ) )
 continue;
```

I think that should do it.

Comment: That will fail if PropertyType is a DataTable, though.

Comment: I didn't know that, makes sense though.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!(typeof(DataTable).IsAssignableFrom(propertyInfo.PropertyType)))
```

The ordering here perhaps seems a little backwards, but for [Type.IsAssignableFrom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx), you want the type you need to work with to come first, and then the type you're checking.